# How to run a simulation using a for loop

Tags: r

Trying to run a simulation in a for loop. The model representing the simulation is :

```
sim.predation(size = 30, n = 100, time = 100, handling.time = 2, draw.plot=FALSE)
```

I want to run a for loop on the `n` variable only from `100:1000`

Comment: What does your function return? What do you want to do with the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sapply(100:1000, function(x){
    res <- sim.predation(size = 30, n=x, time = 100, handling.time = 2, draw.plot=FALSE)
    return(res)
})
```

Or:

```
for (x in 100:1000) {
    sim.predation(size = 30, n=x, time = 100, handling.time = 2, draw.plot=FALSE)
}
```